# zoom of second Image while switch from an image to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magiczoomplus

I have two images of products.

I use Magic Zoom plus 4.0 to zoom in on the images when I mouse over the Images. It works fine until I click then second image; the  second image shows on the main window but when I mouse over it, it already shows the zoom of previous image.

Please help this is my code.

```
<li class="main-image-set ">
    <a href="<?=get_image($product['product_image']);?>" class="MagicZoom thumbnail" id="zoom" title="Cool View!"  rel="zoom-position: right; zoom-align: bottom; zoom-height: 460px; zoom-width: 340px;">
        <img src="<?=get_image($product['product_image']);?>" class="changeimg" id="mainImage" >
    </a>
</li>
<li class="image-additional">
    <a class="thumbnail">
        <img class="galleryimg" src="<?=get_image($product['product_image']);?>" onclick="changeImage1()">
    </a>
</li>
<li class="image-additional">
    <a class="thumbnail">
        <img class="galleryimg" src="<?=get_image($product['product_imageTwo']);?>" id="ok" onclick="changeImage2()">
    </a>
</li>




<script>                                
function changeImage1() {
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "<?=get_image($product['product_image']);?>";
}
function changeImage2() {
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "<?=get_image($product['product_imageTwo']);?>";    
    document.getElementById("zoom").href = "<?=get_image($product['product_imageTwo']);?>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: you probably need to give it a bit of time to load before expecting for it to show the actual image.

Comment: it's not work because I waited for some seconds then mouse over the second image but it still zoom first image. I think it's cached on the browser but how to refresh it I don't know..

Comment: per the installation page you might want to change your code a bit. See https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/

Comment: @Cemal thanks for you. It's useful for me.